# Is this in-sentence list correct or should it be reworded? "Track Waste, Cost, and Assess Trends"

Tags: grammar, lists

At first glance I think it's wrong because it's not truly a list of three because you aren't tracking trends, you're assessing them, but I can't think of a fix other than completely rewording it.

It's trying to say: You can track waste, you can track cost, and you can assess trends.

Comment: Could you put it in a full sentence please?

Comment: @JeffUK Definitely. "Read more here about how you can track waste, cost, and assess trends." We also have it as just a header as written originally: Track Waste, Cost, and Assess Trends.

Comment: @KianaLewis Why not make that addition in your post? Doing so, you place all the information needed in the best spot, for all to read more conveniently.